# previous button not working for music player

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

My music player is almost finished thanks to the help of some people on this site, but I am in need of your help for one last time. I would like to make my previous button check to see if the song playing is the first in the list, and if it is, then keep playing the song and display a message. If it isn't playing the first song in the list, then it should go back a song.

```
   public void prev(View view) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Previous song", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      try {
        if(SONG_NUMBER < songs.size()+1){
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER));
            SONG_NUMBER -=2;
        }
        else {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot play previous song", 
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              prev.setEnabled(false);
            SONG_NUMBER = 0;
        }
        mp.start();
         } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
         }
           catch(NullPointerException e) {
               Log.v(getString(R.string.prevButton), e.getMessage());
           }
  }
```

this is what it is at the moment. Anyone able to help me out?

Comment: What error does logcat show?

Comment: nevermind, i just figured it out before.

Comment: with this one it tried to go previous because the first song in the list was still less then `songs.size()+1` so it would still try to play previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void prev(View view) {
      try {
        if(SONG_NUMBER == 0){
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot play previous song", 
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              prev.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Previous song", 
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER));
            SONG_NUMBER -=2;
        }
        mp.start();
         } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
         }
           catch(NullPointerException e) {
               Log.v(getString(R.string.prevButton), e.getMessage());
           }
  }
```

this is what i changed it to, now it works fine